# why does twilio show calls i've picked up as ringing?

Tags: twilio

I place an outbound call with twilio and it sends an HTTP POST request back to the URL specified by the app corresponding to the token in the `Twilio.Device.setup()` call. The first HTTP POST it makes to that URL has the `CallStatus` as `ringing`. I then pickup and the `CallStatus` is not updated to `in-progress` as I'd expect. In fact it is not updated again until I hang up, several minutes later, at which point it goes from `in-progress` and several seconds later to `completed`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

For your question I suspect we would need to look deeper into the specific calls so my suggestion would be drop an email to our awesome customer support team: help@twilio.com.

If you include the CallSids from several calls that demonstrate the problem, they can take a look at exactly what happened during those calls and work with you to figure out exactly whats going on.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You are watching the wrong POST. 
This ist your makeCall object:

```
client.makeCall({
        url: voice url,
        to: number,
        from: '+14242422989',
        statusCallback: call feedback url,
        statusCallbackMethod: 'POST',
        statusCallbackEvent: ['initiated', 'ringing', 'answered', 'completed']
}
```

I guess you forgot the statusCallback key or statusCallbackEvent key. The Information you are looking for is in the POST from your statusCallback URL

Let me know if this was helpful ;)